# ROW_NUMBER() equivalent function in mysql

Tags: mysql, rank, row-number

Hey every one I want to generate surrogate key by getting Max() from one table in sql I did some thing like that

```
coalesce(max(INDVL_ID), 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

now I have to do same thing in mysql so issue is that I am unable to get alternate of **ROW_NUMBER()** Any one have solution

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 rownum,t.* FROM table t,(select @a:=0)v;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here has been depreciated.   Please use the following in MySQL version 8:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY someField) AS 'row_number'
```

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.Id) AS 'row_num', 
    s.product,
    s.title
FROM supplies AS S
```

Comment: Still working in Server version: 8.0.17 - MySQL Community Server - GPL